# Inkscape - long bezier curves with small, perpendicular hashes at discrete intervals extending from one side of the curve

Tags: inkscape, cartography

I am trying to create a standard cartographic symbol that represents a cliff face, and where the perpendicular hashes indicate the direction of the fall.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Please supply an example image showing what you are trying to achieve. Also please say what you have tried/what has failed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a major software development effort to make Inkscape clever enough to understand map data given in some common format and insert right symbols automatically.

A simple 100% manual way to draw variable length decorated paths with Inkscape is to insert path effect "Pattern along Path".

You draw a single tooth. I have colored it temporarily to red, actually it's black. Copy the tooth to the clipboard.

Duplicate your cliff edge curve, insert path effect Pattern along Path to to the duplicate. Select option Paste Path, repeated, adjust good spacing and set a normal offset to shift the teeth to one side.

[image]

If you planned to export the result as SVG to be used elsewhere you must convert the effect to actual paths (Path > Object to Path) Other software probably knows nothing of Inkscape's effects.

The rounded stroke cap style forgives small placing errors. Have all snap to points ON to avoid them.

BTW you can copy an effected path to the clipboard and paste to another selected path the used effect. Prepare to make at least spacing readjustments.

Comment: Thanks... Very new user here; This sooo very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One refinement is to use a cornered pattern as shown (red) on the image and when you use the "pattern along path" effect to set a normal offset to 0,5 and check the "Offset in unit of pattern size" box below.

This way you have one single path that matches exactly with the original path and that can be edited with the node tool without redoing everything from scratch.

Hope this helps

[image]